# How to translate SQL query to JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpql

I am trying to translate SQL query to JPQL and I cannot find a solution.

```
SELECT * FROM event
INNER JOIN users_events ON users_events.event_id = event.id
INNER JOIN user ON users_events.user_id = SOME_USER_ID
LEFT JOIN pool_option ON pool_option.event_id = event.id
LEFT JOIN vote ON vote.pool_option_id = pool_option.id
GROUP BY event.id
HAVING vote.id is null;
```

My JPQL which writes this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'votes4_.id' in 'having clause'

TypedQuery<Event> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Event e join e.users u left join e.poolOptions po left join po.votes v " +
                "WHERE u.email = :email GROUP BY e.id HAVING v.id is null", Event.class);
```

Vote definitely has attribute "id" and SQL query works in MySQL, but the JPQL does not work.

Comment: why you need having without a count?

Comment: I am trying to get all events, that user has not voted yet. And without GROUP BY and HAVING, I am getting all options that user did not vote (he did vote different option). And with that SQL querry I am getting events that user has not seen/voted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have `HAVING v.id` working, you need to add this column to select clause. Please try with :

```
TypedQuery<Event> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e, v.id FROM Event e join e.users u left join e.poolOptions po left join po.votes v WHERE u.email = :email GROUP BY e.id HAVING v.id is null", Event.class);
```